# Gradle cannot sync Spring Boot project

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

I'm trying to import new project with gradle from start.spring.io in intelij and it cannot download any dependency or import plugins. I see that list of sources is empty. [image]

Any idea how to solve it?

```
   $ ./gradlew build

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Jarek\Downloads\demo\build.gradle' line: 3

* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '2.2.2.RELEASE'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:2.2.2.RELEASE')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Comment: Sitting behind a proxy? Refreshed the cache?

Comment: behind a proxy, i don't think so. It's home network. Refreshed cache? You mean restart idea with  invalidate cache. Doesn't work. It's realy weird. I'm install fresh system on ssd and maven works perfectly.

Comment: Does running the Gradle build from the command line (outside of IntelliJ) work?

Comment: It doesn't work too but reason for it's really confusing.

Comment: The plugin's available from the portal so it should work. Can you try running your build with `--refresh-dependencies`? If that doesn't help, the output of running with `--debug` may help you to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: From logs results that GET for plugin cannot be done.
All logs can be read there https://pastebin.com/9eX746gi

Comment: I think that gradle don't agree to use theirs plugins by me xd

Comment: What's the gradle version? If you are using Gradle 6.0.1, it should work. My guess is you are using Gradle 4.x. If so, you either add https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.springframework.boot legacy plugin application so that the old Gradle can download, or you can download the plugin to your local repo and set your plugin repo to it in settings.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

[(Screenshot from Intellij IDE) The Toggle Offline mode button is the last to the right on the botton bottom tray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mV5LT.png)

There is a likelihood that you have toggled on the OFFLINE MODE for your gradle. Please turn the offline mode off and run `./gradlew build` on your IDE terminal.